# Saved search with groupings latest date

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to do a transaction saved search that show the last bin transfer for each item. That is pretty easy if I just group by item and maximum date. But I always would like it to show the bin of the last transfer and the lot. If I group by those 2 field as well I now get several entries for each item.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this result?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is a bit complicated, but you can use a Formula (Text) and Minimum Summary Type with undocumented NS_CONCAT formula and DISTINCT and then a REGEXP_SUBSTR to pull the data you want

NS_CONCAT - Concatenates all records inside your grouping with a comma delimiter

DISTINCT - Returns only unique values but also orders them

Your formula would look something like this:

```
REPLACE(
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(
        NS_CONCAT(
            DISTINCT TO_CHAR({transaction.trandate},'YYYYMMDDHHMI')||','||{transaction.binnumber}
        ), ',[^,]+,'
    ), ',', ''
)
```

to reverse the order, use:

```
TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - {transaction.datecreated})
```

or

```
TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - {transaction.trandate}, 'FM00000')
```

Comment: The original post puts the records in reverse order (oldest to newest). Use the updated formula segment to order newest to oldest